# az webapp list pull all hostnames for all active webapps

Tags: bash, azure

I'm attempting to pull down all the enabledhostnames associated with all of my webapps.
IE, if I had a basic webapp with the following configuration, I would want to print out test1.com and test2.com.

```
{
    "id": "foobar",
    "name": "foobar",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "kind": "app",
    "location": "East US",
    "properties": {
        "name": "foobar",
        "state": "Running",
        "hostNames": [
            "test1.com",
            "test2.com"
        ],
        "webSpace": "kwiecom-EastUSwebspace",
        "selfLink": "foobar",
        "repositorySiteName": "foobar",
        "owner": null,
        "usageState": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "adminEnabled": true,
        "enabledHostNames": [
            "test1.com",
            "test2.com"
        ]
}
```

When I run the following, I just get the number of hostnames associated with each webapp.

`az webapp list --resource-group resourcegroup1 --query "[?state=='Running']".{Name:enabledHostNames[*]} --output tsv`

The output looks like the following

`2`

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Removing `--output tsv` will result in the hostnames being displayed instead of the number of total, eg:

`az webapp list --resource-group resourcegroup1 --query "[?state=='Running']".{Name:enabledHostNames[*]}`

The output from this command is:

```
[
  {
    "Name": [
      "test1.com",
      "test2.com"
    ]
  }
]
```

Not sure if this is the exact output you are looking for. Apologies if you have already considered this.

Comment: Oh interesting. Thank you! I can work with this and run some bash commands to get what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Hope it works for you! If it does, can you accept the answer so others can see it easily?